# Probability inequality proof

Tags: probability, inequality

I'm stuck on a homework question and don't even know where to start. Here it goes:

If A and B are two events which are not impossible, prove that $$P(A\land B)\times P(A\lor B)\le P(A)\times P(B)$$

Comment: I haven't tried it, but maybe writing $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ would help.

Comment: Tried that, didn't help much

Comment: I think I just solved it using that.  I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$, the original inequality is equivalent to
$$
P(A \cap B) P(A) + P(A \cap B) P(B) - P(A \cap B)^2 - P(A) P(B) \leq 0 \, .
$$
The lefthand side can be factored as
$$
P(A \cap B)[P(A) - P(A \cap B)] + P(B)[P(A \cap B) - P(A)] = [P(A \cap B) - P(B)][P(A) - P(A \cap B)] \, .
$$
Since $B \supseteq A \cap B$ then the first factor is negative (or $0$), and since $A \supseteq A \cap B$ then the second factor is positive (or $0$).  Thus $[P(A \cap B) - P(B)][P(A) - P(A \cap B)] \leq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In general if $d+a=c+b$ and $a\leq b\leq c\leq d$ then:
$$ad=\frac{1}{4}\left(d+a\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\left(d-a\right)^{2}\leq\frac{1}{4}\left(c+b\right)^{2}-\frac{1}{4}\left(c-b\right)^{2}=bc$$

This as a direct consequence of:$$d-a\geq c-b\geq 0$$

This can be applied by taking $a=P(A\cap B)$, $b=P(A)$, $c=P(B)$ and $d=P(A\cup B)$